# What are the conditions to use sqlite3 with iPhone

Tags: ios4

i am using sqlite3 to save the user generated data like name ,phone number and i can use it in any viewcontroller i want but this all is working correctly in ios simulator ,however my problem is that when in test it on real phone my application crashed away , i say so beacause tested the app after commenting sqlite3 statements n runs successfully on ios device.

so what are the conditions for using sqlite3 on iphone and i created the database using terminal and added two tables in it .

I would like to know whether these tables exist after adding it to resources folder explicitly
  or suggest me some other waay to do it.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the package of the application isn't done right. You may take a look at the below sites to learn the how-tos by way of an example:

- [icodeblog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)
- [techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thnx i did the same thing first i created db using terminal then added two tables in it then used those tables